# How to integrate Oauth2 in Drupal for user login?

Tags: oauth-2.0, drupal-7, azure-active-directory

I am planning to integrate Azure Authentication in my Drupal 7 site. I got the Token endpoint URL, Client ID, Client secret from Azure Support team for my site URL. When i tried to connect getting below error "Access token requested for user XXXXX: FAILURE"

Thanks in advance 
Girija

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur for a few reasons:

1. The client application is not registered in the Azure AD or is not added to the user's Azure AD tenant. Ensure that you have registered the application in the correct tenant and ensure that the client id, client secret, and tenant ID in your application registration match what you have in your web.config or app settings.
2. The error usually can also mean you got an incorrect access token for the resource. Are you using Graph API? I have seen this error before when someone tried to get the access token for Azure AD Graph API but used that access token to access Microsoft Graph API. The same could be going on with your drupal site.

Can you please post the full error message here?